# IIS 10 Site Bindings wildcard development machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, binding, wildcard

I have successfully setup IIS on my local development machine (dev branch - setup as localdev.me) but when I went to setup another branch (hotfix - setup as localhotfix.me) I am running into issues. The issues are due to the way the site is setup. The subdomain of the url is used to determine which Database to connect to. So going to host.localdev.me will connect to the host database. So in IIS I have the following settings for the bindings of the site.

```
Type    Host Name        Port  IP Address
http    localdev.me      80    *
http    *.localdev.me    80    *
```

I can ping localdev.me with any subdomain and I get the loopback address as expected. When I then setup the hotfix branch (exactly the same as the dev but with the following bindings) I get name not resolved errors.

```
Type    Host Name           Port  IP Address
http    localhotfix.me      80    *
http    *.localhotfix.me    80    *
```

Is there a reason the first setup would work and not the second? What is perhaps even stranger if I tell IIS to stop I can still ping subdomains on localdev.me and get the loopback address.

I could always get it working by manually specifying the host name in my windows hosts file but I would rather not do that as I would need to go in and edit the file every time we add a new subdomain.

EDIT: These are the specific errors I am getting.

```
ping localhotfix.me
Ping request could not find host localhotfix.me. Please check the name and try again.
```

EDIT2: I have a solution that works fairly well. It requires Acrylic DNS and installation of the Microsoft Loopback Adapter. I set the loopback adapter to a valid IP Address and set the DNS server to 127.0.0.1 then edit the AcrylicHosts file to contain entries for each domain with a wildcard. Once I did all of this I was able to ping localhotfix.me along with *.localhotfix.me. I believe the reason localdev.me worked is because it is a valid domain. The name would resolve at which point I believe IIS was able to take over. But thats really just an educated guess. But kindof makes sense as to why it worked for one and not the other.

Comment: Check your DNS setup first.

Comment: @LexLi I am not sure how DNS will help, could you elaborate? I only want this setting to affect my local machine. Having everyone on my local network routing to my machine when they go to localdev.me will not work at all because there are other developers on the network that will need to use the same url to connect to their machine. Is there a local DNS option in IIS (running on windows 10)?

Comment: Then read about hosts file.

Comment: @LexLi I know how the hosts file works the problem is the hosts file in windows does not support wildcards, so I would need to add an entry for each site (and their subdomains). The real question is why the first site I add in IIS works correctly with the wildcard binding but the second doesnt work. None of this is a problem in production because we can use DNS but I need a solution locally for development that doesnt require manually editing the hosts file.

Comment: Sounds like a design issue but I am not able to verify soon. If you do have support contract with Microsoft you might open a support case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `*.localdev.me` works without a hosts file is because the public DNS for that domain resolves to `127.0.0.1` as long as it is not `localdev.me` or `www.localdev.me`. You can check this using `nslookup *.localdev.me` (replace the asterisk with anything except `www`) while your hosts file is empty. On the other hand, `*.localhotfix.me` is not registered in public DNS at all, which is why you'd need a hosts file entry for those.

Comment: marked as the answer because it answers the question as to why one worked and the other didn't. I have posted the solution I used above though not in any great detail, it was fairly simple to setup once I had all the info.